# SRP and additional logic inside class

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture, single-responsibility-principle

For example, I have a class, which does different requests to some external API:

```
internal class ServiceCore : IDisposable
{
    public ServiceCore(IConfiguration configuration, Func<HttpMessageHandler> handler)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _handler = handler;
        devKey = _configuration.GetSection("ApiBillCom:DevKey").Value;
        client = new HttpClient(_handler())
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("ApiBillCom:ApiUrl").Value)
        };

        if (_sessionId == null || !_sessionId.IsValueCreated)
            SetSessionId();
    }


    public async Task<JToken> ListJTokenAsync(int start, int count, string endpoint, bool nested = false, List<FilterData> filterData = null)
    {
        //....
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> ListAsync<T>(string endpoint, int start, int count, bool nested = false, List<FilterData> filterData = null)
    {
        //.....
    }
```

ok, but each call requires sessionId, which we can get calling `LoginAsync` method before. This `LoginAsync` method can be as private method inside this `ServiceCore` class:

```
private void SetSessionId()
{
    _sessionId = null;
    LoginCore loginCore = new LoginCore(_configuration, _handler);
    _sessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
}

private async Task<string> LoginAsync()
{
```

but then, seems, Single Responsible Principle is violated (because then `ServiceCode` has 2 duties, get (or put) data to API and supports session. I did refactoring and moved it to special class:

```
internal class LoginCore
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly Func<HttpMessageHandler> _handler;

    public LoginCore(IConfiguration configuration, Func<HttpMessageHandler> handler)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _handler = handler;

    }

    internal async Task<string> LoginAsync(string devKey)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Right now no SRP violation, every class has only one duty (`ServiceCore` - work with API, `LoginCore` - get actual sessionId), but I'm not sure, that I need to do it (separate login workflow to another class). Right now I have to pass one parameter to LoginAsync (with private method I have not to do it, because `devKey` is private property inside `ServiceCore`), have to write constructor for `LoginCore` and pass the same dependency injection parameters, which I passed to `ServiceCore`. I have to create `LoginCore` instance before calling `LoginAsync`

I will not use this `LoginCore` somewhere else, only in `ServiceCore`, I need not to have dependency injection (because I need not to replace `LoginCore`, method `LoginAsync` is actual for any calls.
I see only one benefit: I can mark `LoginCore` as:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("BillComRealTest")]
```

and write unit test specially only for `LoginAsync` method, with mock `HttpMessageHandler`.

Should I create this separate class with one method for following SRP or enough to create just private method inside `ServiceCore` ?

Comment: SRP and pattern conversations (and that's what they are) are totally subjective and situation based topics. I personally think sometimes their guidelines and patterns can be taken too far, and following them breaks other normalcy principles. it gets messier if you intending this to be inherited.. if the login architecture is self consistent with this core service, then let it be, if you can foresee it being interchanged, then pass it in, or an interface. if it is a huge bunch of code that only relates to itself and can be reused, make another responsibility of it.

Comment: The SRP does not mean, "every class has only one duty." Start with the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/single-responsibility-principle/info) to learn more about SRP.

Comment: @jaco0646, "one duty" directly depends on "class has only one reason to be changed"

Comment: Oh no. Robert Martin explains it quite differently. I'm sure he would disagree.